# python code with lambda and filter

Tags: python, lambda, filter

Can anyone help me understand the following piece of python code:

```
for i, char in filter(lambda x: x[1] in str1, enumerate(str2)):
    # do something here ...
```

str1 and str2 are strings, I sort of understand that the "lambda x: x[1] in str1" is filtering condition, but why x[1] ?

How can I convert this for loop into a lower level (but easier to understand) python code ?

Thanks

Comment: `enumerate` returns an iterable object contain the indices and items, so the `x` would be a tuple contain each element with its index and `x[1]` is the item (character) itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears functionality equivalent to:

```
for i, char in enumerate(str2):
    if char in str1:
        # do something here
```

`filter` is taking a list of tuples consisting of the index and elements of `str2`, filtering out those elements that do not appear in `str1`, then returning a iterable of the remaining indices and elements from `str2`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `enumerates`.

Enumerates returns tuples of `(index, value)` for an iterable of values.

`x` is a tuple of index, char.

I would write `lambda (index, char): char in str1` for clarity